# How do I prompt a user with file "Save As" dialog using a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I created an Excel macro to replace data from "Quote" to "Invoice", but after running the macro, I wish for the macro to continue to run and stop at: "Save As..." mode so that the user can provide a name for the file manually and choose it's proper file location.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` just before the end of your code.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, i will try that and thanks for the reference lynk.